# How to generate a `kwargs` list?

Tags: python, keyword-argument

From an external file I generate the following dictionary:

```
mydict = { 'foo' : 123, 'bar' : 456 }
```

Given a function that takes a `**kwargs` argument, how can generate the keyword-args from that dictionary?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
def foo(**kwargs):
    pass

foo(**{ 'foo' : 123, 'bar' : 456 })
```

Comment: Or, if the function takes _only_ `kwargs`, and `mydict` contains all the arguments, leave off all the `*`s.

Comment: @agf So I could just pass the dictionary? What if the function takes `(self, **kwargs)`, can I do `obj.func(mydict)`?

Comment: @Paul No -- Only if you rewrote it to take `(self, kwargs)`.

Comment: @agf: That's not really even close to the same thing.

Comment: If he's writing `foo`, he can get a dictionary of arguments from a dictionary without using keyword arguments -- I've seen a beginner think you have to use keyword arguments to pass a dictionary.